# Clearing a div which is used by mixitup filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used mixitup js to filter the plugin type in which each div is wrap in a column.

The main point is I can't  use `clear: both;` CSS property.
I have achieved this issue in other sites by using

```
.parent-class .column-class:nth-of-type(3n+1){
   clear:both;
}
```

But in mixitup I cannot target the nth item because of the filter, If I click in free tab than the nth item which I was targeting will be replaced by other div.

[you can view the issue in this link but make sure your browser width is less than 1100px and more than 992px](http://skynet.wensolutions.com/wensolutions-site/plugins/)

Due to the long text of contact form 7 which comes in 2 lines the height of the div is more than others. I want to target 4th element for `min-width: 992px;` and clear that div.

HTML structure is :

```
<section class="plugin-listing-page">
<div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="plugin-type">
            <ul id="filters" class="clearfix post-filter-controls">
                <li><span class="filter active-onload theme-demo btn-default" data-filter=".all">All</span></li>

                <li><span class="filter theme-demo btn-default" data-filter=".free">Free</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter theme-demo btn-default" data-filter=".premium">Premium</span></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="filtr-container" id="pluginlist">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 all listplugin free" data-bound="">
                <div class="single-plugin-list">
                    <div class="single-plugin-list-image">
                        <a href="">
                           <img src="https://pippinspluginscom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/plugin.png" >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-plugin-list-content">
                        <h4 class="text-title"><a href="#">Test</a></h4>
                        <a class="theme-demo btn-default animate-arrow pull-left" href="#">View Detail<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt"></span></a>
                        <span class="theme-green pull-right">Free</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 all listplugin premium" data-bound="">
                <div class="single-plugin-list">
                    <div class="single-plugin-list-image">
                        <a href="">
                           <img src="https://pippinspluginscom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/plugin.png" >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-plugin-list-content">
                        <h4 class="text-title"><a href="#">Test</a></h4>
                        <a class="theme-demo btn-default animate-arrow pull-left" href="#">View Detail<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt"></span></a>
                        <span class="theme-green pull-right">Free</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS for mixitup is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
       var filterList = {
            init: function () {
                $('#pluginlist').mixItUp({
                    selectors: {
                        target: '.listplugin',
                        filter: '.filter'
                    },
                    load: {
                         filter: '.tables' // show app tab on first load
                    },callbacks: {
                    onMixEnd: function(state) {
                        if(state.activeFilter == '.listplugin')
                            $('.wil').addClass('active')
                    }
                }
                });
            }
        };
        filterList.init();
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#filters li .active-onload').click();
    },100);
   })(jQuery);    
});
```

[image]
Is there any solution for clearing the height of the div so that it always floats left of the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways we can solve this issue. However, I would go for css based approach

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1100px){     
  .single-plugin-list-content h4 a{
    font-size: 90%; // or smaller
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**:

If you can use flex then this will fix the issue. It should work on all screens. However you can add this to `min-width: 992px` media query. The decision is yours.

```
#pluginlist{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: I can't reduce the font size, It should be identical to other pages font size.

Comment: I also can't use min-height for heading tag. It could be of two line or more than that. It will be best if I can clear the height of the column. So that the other column will start as in a new line.